# Is there a way to get a Silverlight app and a Flash app to communicate?

Tags: flash, silverlight

I'm looking for any way to get a flash app to communicate with a silverlight app, and vice versa.

Are there any drawbacks to communication between the two apps?  What are (or not) you able to communicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you could try communicating via the DOM on the page in which the controls are hosted. I believe both have hooks into it from inside their programming environments.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, right after I asked this question, I find this article about a project called Microbe that passes a ball between Java and Silverlight, althought I can't find the actual site that hosts this idea.

Anyway, here's the [article](http://adamkinney.com/blog/252/default.aspx).  If I can find the actually site I'll link it in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Haha, nice, I was going to suggest using Javascript to do that, post more when you actually do it!

Comment: I've been looking all day and have come up empty, but if I find anything I'll definitely include it so everyone can see an example of this.